# Why does "const" get used in this example?

Tags: c++, constants

Hello I'm wondering why is `const` used at the "get" functions in this class?

```
class Album {

public:
    Album(string c, Artist* a, string t, int y, int no):barCode(c), artist(a), title(t), year(y), noCopiesSold(no){}
    const string& getBarCode() const {return barCode;}
    Artist* getArtist() const {return artist;}
    const string& getTitle() const {return title;}
    int getYear() const {return year;}
    int getNoCopiesSold() const {return noCopiesSold;}
    void setBarCode(string value) {barCode = value;}
    void setArtist(Artist* value) {artist = value;}
    void setTitle(string value) {title = value;}
    void setYear(int value) {year = value;}
    void setNoCopiesSold(int value) {noCopiesSold = value;}

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Album& album)
    {
        out << album.artist->getName() << " " << album.barCode << " " << album.title << " " << album.year << " " << album.noCopiesSold << endl;
        return out;
    }

private:
    string barCode;
    Artist* artist;
    string title;
    int year;
    int noCopiesSold;
};
```

Comment: imagine what happens if it was not there, and you wanted to call a get on a const object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is "const used at the "get" functions in this class?

For **const-correctness**.

1. By making a function `const`, it implies that the function is not
   changing any non-static member variable inside it and no other non-`const` function is called inside
   this method
2. The function now can be called using a `const` object also (otherwise
   results in compiler error)
3. Many library functions make use of `const` correct methods; so const-correctness make your method compatible with it (e.g. less than operator -- `bool <Class>::operator < (const Class&) const`)

Answer (score 3):

`const` tells the compiler that the method does not change the object. This means that it is safe to operate on `const` objects (as well as non-`const` objects). It also enables the compiler to make some optimizations

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the function qualifiers - for the `string` getters (barcode, title), you are returning a `const` reference to a data member - allowing the referenced value to be mutated would break encapsulation in the class.

For this reason, returning `Artist*` is bad (or at best suspect) design.

Comment: it is just an example i got for my lab assignment ... the reaso my be because the teacher used char[] not string msot of the time...

Comment: Thanks - I expect the gist of your question was regarding `const` function qualifiers, but wanted to point out that it has meaning and weight on return values also.